# Pass dictionary to Excel macro using win32com and comtypes

Tags: python, excel, com, win32com, comtypes

I am using Python to unit test Excel macros. When testing the following macro I need to pass a dictionary object to it.

code in testDict.xlsm:

```
Function GetItemCount(dict As Variant) As Integer
    GetItemCount = dict.Count
End Function
```

My test code looks like this and is based on [test_dict.py](https://github.com/enthought/comtypes/blob/master/comtypes/test/test_dict.py) in the comtypes project:

test_comtypes_w_dict.py

```
from comtypes.client import CreateObject
import win32com.client as win32

d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary", dynamic=True)

d.Add("Test", "An item")

filename = 'testDict.xlsm'
xl = win32.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(filename)
count = xl.Application.Run(filename+'!Module1.GetItemCount', d)

assert count == 1
```

When running the test, TypeError is raised.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\[..]\test_comtypes_w_dict.py", line 11, in <module>
        count = xl.Application.Run(filename+'!Module1.GetItemCount', d)
    File "C:\Users\[..]\AppData\Local\Temp\gen_py\3.9\00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046x0x1x9.py", line 44654, in Run
        return self._ApplyTypes_(259, 1, (12, 0), ((12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17)), 'Run', None,Macro
File "C:\Users\[..]\venv\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 467, in _ApplyTypes_
        self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(dispid, 0, wFlags, retType, argTypes, *args), TypeError: Objects for SAFEARRAYS must be sequences (of sequences), or a buffer object.
```

I have tried removing `dynamic=True` from the call to CreateObject. Then the test runs, but I get an exception in Excel:

> Run-time error '424':
>
> Object required

When debugging in the Excel VBA IDE and running TypeName(dict), the result is "Variant()".

How do I pass the dictionary to the macro in a way that it is properly recognized?

As a workaround I will attempt to generate the dictionary in a macro, return it to Python and pass it to the macro that I want to test. I would however like to avoid this convoluted method if possible.

Comment: If it's not a silly question, why are you using two different methods (comtypes and win32com) to create dispatch interfaces? If instead of the CreateObject call, I use win32.dispatch("Scripting.Dictionary"), my version of your code runs fine and passes the dictionary correctly to the Excel test function, and gets a count of 1 back.

Comment: @DS_London Not a silly question. I started out with win32com, but did not find CreateObject in it. Is it included?

Comment: You are using the method already .... the win32.Dispatch() method either creates a new object or attaches to one that is already running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code above is mixing two different libraries for creating COM objects.

Replace

```
d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary", dynamic=True)
```

with

```
d = win32.Dispatch('Scripting.Dictionary')
```

and dispense with comtypes, unless it is needed for some other feature.

Comment: Is there a list of possible values that may be passed to `Dispatch`? I would like to create a VBA Collection from within Python, but I can't figure out how.

Comment: @rudolfbyker Dispatch will take anything that `win32com` can convert to a `Variant` (which is pretty much anything). I am not sure you can create an actual VBA Collection in Python: you can receive one from Excel (eg from a `createMyCollection` function) modify it and use it as a parameter to another Excel function, or (and this is much more of an effort) create you own COM object in Python that 'looks' like a VBA Collection (ie supports the same COM interface).